# Movement of object between planes in scenekit ios

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to make ludo game in scenekit but i dont know how to make an object move from one plane (boxes in ludo game for path ) to another plane. PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 0):

It is simple just add the position to your SCNNode() object.

```
    let boxNode1 = SCNNode(geometry: cubeGeometry1)
    boxNode1.position = SCNVector3(X,Y,Z)
```